# Defining a subgroup of $GL(2,7)$ in GAP

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computational-mathematics, gap

Considering this resent [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/905816/8581) in which $|G|=42$, I am thinking of making this subgroup concrete in GAP environment. Maybe, if the structure of $G$ was [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/375496/groups-of-order-42-and-classification) then, we would use an appropriate mapping for this aim by doing the inverse map. However, I started to examine the problem by doing some basic related codes as below, I got an error instead!

```
gap> g:=GeneralLinearGroup(2,Field(Z(7)));;
     e:=Elements(g);;
     f:=AllSubgroups(g);;
     Filtered(f, t->Order(f[t])=42);
```

Any suggestions? Thanks for the time.

---

**Edit:**  I did a terrible job. The codes are changed as:

```
gap> g:=GeneralLinearGroup(2,Field(Z(7)));;
     f:=AllSubgroups(g);;
     e:=Elements(f);;
     Filtered(e, t->Order(t)=42);
```

Comment: The last command is wrong. `t` is an element of list `f`, so you should check that `t` has order 42 (not `f[t]` which would return `t`-th position of `f` if `t` is a positive integer, and would give an error otherwise).

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: Oh! yes. That's terrible. It should have had `h:= Elements(h)` and then using `Filtered...`  code.

Comment: Really? There is no `h` in your example. Then, in the 2nd version of the code `Elements` just reorders the list of subgroups in a different order. And after your edit, `e[t]` still will not work, as `t` is not an index. What do you want to calculate - all subgroups of order 42?

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: I was thinking of finding the possible subgroup of order $42$. I changed it to `e=Elements(f)`

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov: As you noted, I edited the codes but as I have already thought it is not helpful. Just $96$ subgroups of order $42$. I think, I should delete this question. Thanks.

Comment: "resent post" (i.e. post sent more than once) or "recent post"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `AllSubgroups`, the correct form is shown below:

```
gap> g:=GL(2,7);
GL(2,7)
gap> f:=AllSubgroups(g);;
gap> Length(last);
1704
gap> h:=Filtered(f,t->Size(t)=42);;
gap> Length(h);
96
gap> h[1];
Group([ [ [ Z(7)^2, Z(7)^3 ], [ 0*Z(7), Z(7) ] ], 
  [ [ Z(7)^4, Z(7)^2 ], [ 0*Z(7), Z(7)^2 ] ], 
  [ [ Z(7), Z(7)^2 ], [ Z(7)^5, Z(7)^3 ] ] ])
```

However, thinking in terms of conjugacy classes may be more efficient for larger groups:

```
gap> g:=GL(2,7);
GL(2,7)
gap> cc:=ConjugacyClassesSubgroups(g);;
gap> Length(cc);
84
gap> cc42:=Filtered(cc,c->Size(Representative(c))=42);;
gap> Length(cc42);
12
gap> Representative(cc42[1]);
Group([ [ [ Z(7), 0*Z(7) ], [ 0*Z(7), Z(7)^2 ] ], 
  [ [ Z(7)^2, 0*Z(7) ], [ 0*Z(7), Z(7)^4 ] ], 
  [ [ Z(7)^0, Z(7)^5 ], [ 0*Z(7), Z(7)^0 ] ] ])
```